# Calculating $z=(1+i)^8(1-i\sqrt{3})^{-6}$ by applying the trigonometric form of a complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> By applying the trigonometric form of complex number calculate:
> $$z=(1+i)^8(1-i\sqrt{3})^{-6}$$

I trained different problems (it starts finding the angle fi then find the trigonometric form of complex number then applying the algebraic operations to it...) but I'm stuck in this problem please help...

Comment: Use $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{\pi i/4},\,1-i\sqrt{3}=2e^{-\pi i/3}$.

Comment: i havent arrive yet learning "e". But i have one idea can i do the one with power negative 1/(1-sqrt3)^6 then i know how to do till the end.

Comment: In that case, use $1+i=\sqrt{2}(\cos\tfrac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\tfrac{\pi}{4})$ etc. together with $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)=\cos(\theta+\phi)+i\sin(\theta+\phi)$.

Comment: Can you turn the factors to the trigonometric form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without the trigonometric form:**

$$(1+i)^2=1-1+2i$$ and $$(1+i)^8=16.$$

Then

$$(1-i\sqrt3)^3=1-3i\sqrt3-9+3\sqrt3i=-8$$ and $$(1-i\sqrt3)^{-6}=\frac1{64}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $z_1=(1+i)$ and $z_2 = 1-i\sqrt{3}$.

Hints:

1. If $z = a + bi$, then $|z| = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$.  Find $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$.
2. If $z = a + bi$, then $\theta = \arctan \frac ba$.  Find $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$.
3. Once you have $|z_1|, |z_2|, \theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, use DeMoivre's Theorem: $$(z_1)^n = |z_1|^n(\cos n \cdot \theta_1 + i \sin n \cdot \theta_1) \\ (z_2)^n = |z_2|^n(\cos n \cdot \theta_2 + i \sin n \cdot \theta_2)$$ and simplify each equation.  Call these simplified equations $w_1$ and $w_2$.
4. Multiply the result of $w_1$ and $w_2$.

**Addendum:** The alternative way of writing DeMoivre's Theorem (which JG was referring to in the original comment above) is using $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta = e^{i \theta}$, but usually this is for advanced use (i.e. college courses); high school classes will often use the $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ notation or even $\text {cis } \theta$, which means the same thing.

The equations are

> $$(z_1)^n = |z_1|^ne^{i \cdot n\theta_1} \\ (z_2)^n = |z_2|^ne^{i \cdot n\theta_2}$$